# Need to display multicolored text in a single text area control or any text displaying control

Tags: java, gwt

```
public class Hello1 implements EntryPoint {  

    final RichTextArea textArea = new RichTextArea();  
    final Label counter = new Label("Number of characters: 0");    

    public void onModuleLoad() {    
        RootPanel.get().add(textArea); 
        RootPanel.get().add(counter); 

        addlistener();   
    }     

    private void addlistener() {  
        textArea.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {  
            public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent keyUpEvent) {  
                counter.setText(" Number of characters:"+textArea.getText().length()); 
                int i = textArea.getText().length();  

                if (i >4) {  
                    textArea.getFormatter().setForeColor("red"); 
                } else {    
                    textArea.getFormatter().setForeColor("black");  
                }    
            }   
        });   
    } 
}
```

I want to create a comment field using GWT. If the comment length exceeds the allowed length, then mark the exceed substring in red color.

Answer (score 0):

Several resources exist for this question on a standard web search but:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/enforceform.shtml

Will provide for what you need. On a side note, this is not a well formed question since it doesn't show your own efforts to code and implement a resolution. SO isn't meant to find resources for you but more to help you when you have exhausted your own knowledge and skills and can't resolve your code problem.

Comment: you can check the code above ,here i am using GWT i am able to display the multi colored text inside the textarea but i am getting some defect

Comment: @sid is the page you need this to occur on live or web accessible? if so what is the URL?

Comment: @Jax it should occur on live.